# s3-streams Missing env AWS_REGION

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, stream, sdk, aws-sdk

s3-streams threw the following error with no clear details

```
Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ([object Object])
    at S3ReadStream.emit (events.js)
    at S3ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit domain.js
```

GitHub issue: https://github.com/izaakschroeder/s3-streams/issues/38

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: set missing environment variable

`AWS_REGION=YOUR_REGION_HERE`

> AWS SDK expecting region environment variable [AWS_REGION] for
>   authentication  If you don't specify a Region, the SDK uses in the US
>   East (N. Virginia) Region (us-east-1)

GitHub Answer: https://github.com/izaakschroeder/s3-streams/issues/38#issuecomment-628296822